# Deforming a differential equation with no solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Say we have a linear differential equation of the form $$L y(x)=0$$ and for a particular set of boundary conditions, there is no non trivial solution to this equation.

Is it possible for there to exist non trivial solutions to the following equation?

$$L y(x)=V(x)y(x)$$

With the same set of boundary conditions. Where $V(x)$ is a differentiable function of $x$.

My initial guess is no because if treat $V(x)$ as a perturbation, we may rewrite our equation above as

$$y(x)=\int dz G(x,z) V(z)y(z)$$

Where $G(x,z)$ is a Green's function for the differential operator $L$. The usual prescription for perturbation theory is to put the zeroth order solution in the right hand side to get the first order correction. But this gives us that there is no first order correction. We could continue this and see that there is no correction to all orders.

This is all very schematic and I'm not sure if this argument really proves the non existence of non trivial solutions for the deformed equation.

So to summarize my question, is it possible to obtain non trivial solutions to a linear differential equation with no solution by adding a term of the form $V(x)y(x)$?

I would like to understand this also in the context of partial differential equations, not only ordinary. Hopefully my notation can be properly generalized to the partial case.

**Edit**

It is true that for special values of $V(x)$, in particular constant values which are eigenvalues of the operator $L$ are candidates for non trivial solutions. I'd like to avoid those examples, so let's assume that $V'(x)\neq 0$.